# Ajax/AngularJS TypeError: $http is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

If got following Ajax/AngularJS function and I really don't know why I get the "TypeError: $http is not a function" error. Someone has an idea?

```
<script>
    var map;
    var data;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });

        httpCall();
    }

    function httpCall($http) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
            data: "data="+ data,
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(response){
                alert(data);
                for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: {
                            lat: parseFloat(data[i].lat),
                            lng: parseFloat(data[i].lng)
                        },
                        map: map
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: you cant inject angularJS-services into normal javascript functions. It has to be a angular-module. (controller, directive, service etc)

Comment: Thx for your help. How do i go to work?

Comment: I reccomend taking a look at some basic angularJS tutorials. But if you just want to do simple rest-calls going with angularJS might be a bit overkill. You could use jQuery instead, with $.get()

Comment: I can inject JQuery-services in javascript functions?

Comment: @Etse : I edited my code, I get the error "$ is not defined". It's another way of implementation, i guess?

Comment: jQuery is a different framework, you would need to include jquery-sourcefiles for it to be defined.

Comment: i found it. Still got some errors but I will search for it. Thx for the help!